# What does a LoadLoad barrier really do?

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

In Java, when we have two threads sharing the following variables:

```
int a;
volatile int b;
```

if thread 1 does:

```
a = 5;
b = 6;
```

Then a StoreStore barrier is inserted between these two instructions and 'a' is being flushed back to the main memory.

Now if thread 2 does:

```
if(b == 6)
 a++;
```

a LoadLoad barrier is inserted between and we have a guarantee that if the new value of 'b' is visible then new value of 'a' is visible as well. But how actually this is achieved? Does LoadLoad invalidate the CPU caches/registers? Or just instructs a CPU to fetch the values of the variables that follow read from volatile again from CPU?

I have found this information about LoadLoad barrier (http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html):

> LoadLoad Barriers The sequence: Load1; LoadLoad; Load2 ensures that
>   Load1's data are loaded before data accessed by Load2 and all
>   subsequent load instructions are loaded. In general, explicit LoadLoad
>   barriers are needed on processors that perform speculative loads
>   and/or out-of-order processing in which waiting load instructions can
>   bypass waiting stores. On processors that guarantee to always preserve
>   load ordering, the barriers amount to no-ops.

but it does not really explain how this is achieved.

Comment: The answer depends on the processor architecture - the same document has a table with each processor instruction that shows that `LoadLoad` is a no-op on x86 for example.

Comment: then how does it work at all? I mean, after StoreStore the values are flushed back in the memory. But then how does the thread 2 is supposed to see them? If that LoadLoad evaluates to no-op then thread 2 can continue using cached values.

Comment: because the processor's memory model is strong enough that it guarantees that it will be the case. What I'm trying to say is that Java makes a promise that if you use volatile, something will / will not happen. How this is implemented in the JVM is processor specific and uses ad hoc instructions (or no instruction if that is relevant). You can read more about the LoadLoad/x86 point here: http://altair.cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2012-July/009615.html

Comment: You could read further on CPU architectures where LoadLoad is not a no-op, such as ARM. Seems to be heavy stuff though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will give one example on how this is achieved.  You can read more on the details [here](http://brooker.co.za/blog/2012/09/10/volatile.html).  For x86 processors as you indicated LoadLoad ends up being no-ops.  In the article I linked Mark points out that

> Doug lists the StoreStore, LoadLoad and LoadStore

So in essence the only barrier needed is a StoreLoad for x86 architectures.  So how is this achieved on low level?

This is an excerpt from the blog:

**Here's the code it generated for both volatile and non-volatile reads:**

```
nop                       ;*synchronization entry
mov    0x10(%rsi),%rax    ;*getfield x
```

**And for volatile writes:**

```
xchg   %ax,%ax
movq   $0xab,0x10(%rbx)
lock addl $0x0,(%rsp)     ;*putfield x
```

The `lock` instruction is the StoreLoad as listed by Doug's cookbook.  But the lock instruction also synchronizes all reads with other processes as [listed](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)

> Locked instructions can be used to synchronize data written by one
>   processor and read by another processor.

This reduces the overhead of having to issue LoadLoad LoadStore barriers for volatile loads.

All that being said, I will reiterate what assylias noted.  The way it happens should not be important to a developer (if you are interested in processor/compiler implementer that is another story).  The `volatile` keyword is kind of an interface saying

1. You will get the most up to date read which is written by another thread
2. You will not get burned by JIT compiler optimizations.

Comment: Nice link. I would silghtly rephrase: "*You will get the most up to date read which is written by another thread*" => "*You will eventually see the writes when subsequently reading from the volatile variable - "eventually" meaning almost immediately in practice*" ;-)

Comment: Actually, it is important if you are interested about on what hardware your application runs fastest or about how to achieve highest performance. We were hoping to benefit from going to a four-socket Xeon (64 SMT) much more than we eventually did. If you have no control over the hardware or run on single sockets only, that might not be an issue, but concurrency implementation details and how they affect scalability on larger machines can certainly influence a design if they are known early on.

Comment: @RalfH I was speaking on behalf of the average developer using `volatile` keyword.  Generally speaking a developer should not need to worry about how volatile is implemented.   Did you see an instance when knowing the underlying architecture changes how you would use volatile differently?

Comment: :) No, since I do not know how the hardware does it, either, I’d rather do profiling. Which is how I noticed that a volatile get like in ConcurrentHashMap is not good for performance, so we ended up replacing these by CopyOnWriteHashMaps as soon as their content stabilized. Hardware details are instesting though if you want to know what's coming. Like I would like to know what exactly Hardware Transactional Memory like in Haswell means for Java concurrency.

Comment: Ok, that's puzzling :) I'm not sure if my understanding is correct: because the LoadLoad barrier on x86 is a no-op, Marc's program has generated a StoreLoad barrier? (which is the line starting with "lock"). And if the volatile read has generated an extra instruction (lock) why does he say that we can expect volatile reads to be free?     Coming back to my original question, if we added to Marc's example a read of a non-volatile after the read of a volatile, would the "lock" instruction do the magic (ensure visibility of a non-volatile)?

Comment: @Janek If you read a bit further he mentions `It appears as though reads to volatile variables are not free in Java on x86, or at least on the tested setup.`  And the StoreLoad is generated by the write of a volatile variable, not read.  The added 25% for volatile load compared to non-volatile-load is because of x86 cache coherence.

Comment: @Jarek To answer your other question.  `(ensure visibility of a non-volatile)`  Only if you do a write to the volatile field.  Otherwise there is no happens-before relationship and thus you wouldn't need to worry about the visibility.  If you did do the write the `lock` instruction seems to guarantee visibility.  I am making that assertion based on `data written by one processor and read by another processor`

Comment: "I wrote a very small toy program which accessed a volatile variable in a loop" - thought that by accessed he meant read. It's a pity he didn't attach the source. So the bottom line is that, the StoreLoad barrier that is inserted when writing to a volatile does all the job necessary for other processors to see the memory changes before that write. And then the volatile read is exactly the same (asm instructions wise) as non-volatile read. And to find out exactly how this StoreLoad barrier propages the memory changes to other processors I should study lock instruction and maybe xchg?

Comment: `lock instruction and maybe xchg` yes, and also the cache coherence protocol: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence

Answer (score 0):

> If that LoadLoad evaluates to no-op then thread 2 can continue using cached values.

This is covered by the "Can Order" table in the cookbook.

The programming order is

```
read b
read a
write a
```

by "caching a", you mean the code is reordered

```
read a
...
read b
```

This reordering is prohibited.

Comment: I actually meant real caching in the CPU cache, not instruction reordering.

Comment: @zhong I think Janek's concern was, 'how can a field be up to date in a processor's register if it never initiates a load after a write by another processor'.